# dictionary inside 2 loops to save to a single file

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, dictionary, connection-pooling

I intend to write in a single file (for each function), but inside the "loop in the loop" I got trapped.

It's working except the storage/ save part,
now writes a file for each inner loop: ## def t2(): ##

But I wish to improve and also work with the current 'dic' or 'list' in the next pool/ funtion t'x'(): and so on, to avoid have to open the csv in the jorney.

what's the lesson over here? :p
It's my 1st data scrape, I'm new to python!

```
import    

def t0(url): # url
soup ('http://www.foo.net')
return soup

def t1(): # 1st_pool
    soup = t0()
    dic = {}
    with open('dic.csv', 'w') as f:
        for x in range(15):
            try:
                collect
                dic[name] = link
                f.write('{0};{1}\n'.format(name, link))
            except:
                pass

    return dic

def t2(): # 2nd_pool
    dic = t1()
    dic2 = {}
    for k,v in dic.items():
        time.sleep(3)
        with open(k+'_dic.csv', 'w') as f:
            for x in range(13):
                try:
                    collect
                    dic2[name] = link
                    f.write('{0};{1}\n'.format(name, link))
                except:
                    pass

    return ###############

def t3(): ... # 3rd_pool
def t4(): ... # 4th_pool
def t5(): ... # 5th_pool
def t6(): ... # full_path /to /details
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're trying to do here? It's not clear how you intend to use these functions, or what your end goal is.

Comment: I'm trying to save in a individual.csv each funtion, and use the data from the current function to fuel the next one, but i'm trapped inside the "double loop"

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the problem and explain what you expect the behavior to be. The code you've posted doesn't do that; it won't even parse with the empty `import` at the top of the file. There's no definition for `collect` and it's not at all clear what `t3` through `t6` do.

Answer (score 0):

As I mention early, the "problem" resides only in the fact that was creating a individual *.csv (to not overwrite the previous loop) for each loop, so now I figured out how to create a single file.csv for each function:

```
def t2(): # 2nd_pool
    dic = t1()
    dic2 = {}
    for k,v in dic.items():
        time.sleep(3)
        ##
        for x in range(13):
            try:
                collect
                dic2[name] = link
                ##
            except:
                pass
    ##
    with open('dic2.csv', 'w') as f:
        for n,j in dic2.items():
            f.write('{0};{1}\n'.format(n, j))
    ##
    return dic2
```

I simply moved the "*.csv operation" ( ## represent the chages) to the end of the function, outside of the "double loop", and the dictionary it's also available in the next function # t3():# and so on.

I was trying to achieve that without write the extra loop, so if someone can provide a better alternative, I would like to learn!